# I accidentally poured Coca-Cola on my computer and it's the only one I have for studying

Tags: repair, pc

To solve this, I tried to dry it, and it kinda works. My PC get turned on but after that it began to turn off suddenly and the  mouse is moving without any movement from me. How can I solve this please?

Comment: Disassemble all affected parts and clean them with distilled water. You must not use regular water! Let it dry and hope some chip did not get burned.

Comment: heat up the water first, so that it dissolves grime faster

Comment: Oh yeah... the pepsi syndrome.   You pour any cola on a control panel, it shorts out.   You'da been OK if you were drinking 7-up because its an un-cola...

Comment: Remove all batteries before doing this.

Answer (score 3):

I poured porridge into mine, and it stopped working. I dismantled it, cleaned the residues off the main board with de-ionised water, dried it with disposable tissue, then followed with a rinse with isopropyl alcohol. It worked again after that. YMMV.

Comment: What's the role of isopropyl alcohol?

Comment: @MituRaj   removes non-water soluble residues likes fats, and is water miscible so removes final traces of water. It worked, and now I have a new solvent kicking around in my workroom.

Comment: Isoproyl can be purchased in nearly 100% strength at drug stores.   The stuff you get in a supermarket is about 70% alcohol, 30% water (sometimes 91% alcohol).   The 100% stuff is best for electronics.   Note it's SUPER FLAMABLE though - like gasoline flammable.